# wagtailでhtmlで表示したい

Tags: python, html, django

**質問内容**

DjangoのInlinePanelを使ってwagtailで以下のモデルを実装してみました。
公式ドキュメントを参考に作成しました。管理者側はしっかりと反映されており、データを打ち込めるのですがユーザー画面に反映されません。（エラーは出ません。）そこでhtmlの書き方に問題があると考えます。具体的にはselfの部分が間違えているはずです。ですのでこの部分をpageに変えてみたりarticle_fieldに変えたりtitleに変えてみましたがエラーも出ることなく反映もされませんでした。

何に変えるべきなのでしょうか？経験豊かな先輩方のお力をぜひお菓子いただければと思います。

**コード**

```py
from django.db import models
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField, StreamField
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, PageChooserPanel, StreamFieldPanel, MultiFieldPanel, InlinePanel
from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel

from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey

from menu_header_wagtail.models import HeaderPage
from wagtail.snippets.edit_handlers import SnippetChooserPanel

class ArticleBlock(models.Model):
    article_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=True)
    heading = RichTextField(features=["bold", "italic"], blank=True)
    thumbnail = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )
    article_link = models.URLField(max_length=500, blank=True, default='')

    panels = [
        FieldPanel("article_title"),
        ImageChooserPanel("thumbnail"),
        FieldPanel("heading"),
        FieldPanel("article_link"),
      ]

class ArticleField(ArticleBlock):
    page = ParentalKey('article.ArticleTitlePage', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='article_field')

class ArticleTitlePage(Page):
    """Article Index model"""

    template = "article/article_title.html"

    header = models.ForeignKey(
        HeaderPage,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+')

    page_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        SnippetChooserPanel('header'),
        FieldPanel('page_title'),
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
            InlinePanel("article_field", label="title"),
        ], heading = "article_info"),
    ]
```

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags %}

{% block content %}

<p>{{ self.page_title }}</p>
<!--以下のselfが怪しい-->
<h2>{{ self.article_title }}</h2>

</a>

{% endblock content %}
```

**試してみたこと**

```
{% block content %}

<p>{{ self.page_title }}</p>
<h2>{{ article.article_title }}</h2>
{{ article_info }}
{{ heading }}

{{ self.article_info }}
{{ self.heading }}


{{ page.article_info }}
{{ page.heading }}

{{ article_field.value.article_info }}
{{ article_field.heading }}

{{ self.value.heading }}
```

などとにかく変数の書き方を変えて行ってみましたが、エラーはないものの表示されません。

Comment: この記事の内容が似ていますね。[wagtail(DjangoCMS)でHTML上の{{ self.article_title }}が表示されない。](https://teratail.com/questions/282871) 何か参考になれば。

Comment: ありがとうございました。そちらを参考に無事解決いたしました。